# Error getting user ID from Twitter using Tweepy with Python , 'function' object has no attribute 'id' or 'id_str'

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy, text-mining

I'm trying to get user ID and `screen_name` from Twitter using Tweepy with Python, but it gives me the same error. I'm looking for a solution but none come out. Code I use:

```
import tweepy
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)
screen_name = "geeksforgeeks"
user = api.get_user
ID = user.id_str
print("The ID of the user is : " + ID)
```

Output

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. See how there's a button in your IDE, underneath the error message, labelled `SEARCH STACK OVERFLOW` in all caps? Did you try clicking that? What happened when you tried clicking that? [Also, please do not upload images of errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551), and read [ask] to get a general sense of expectations here. You should try to solve the problem yourself first, which includes reading error messages and [doing research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) to understand them.

Comment: Try to [go over the code carefully](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) to look for problems, and to test your assumptions. For example, where the code says `user.id_str`, what do you expect `user` to be? Why? Where did that value come from? It came from `user = api.get_user`, right? Is `api.get_user` correct? What do you expect that to do? Why? (Hint: where the code - correctly - says `tweepy.API(auth)`, why does that *not* just say `tweepy.API`? What would go wrong if it were like that instead?)

Answer (score 0):

You're setting `user` to the method `API.get_user`.
As the error says, that method does not have an `id_str` attribute.
You probably want to call the method instead.